# GCP - Static hosting - Redirects to /index.html

Tags: redirect, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to serve a static website using GCP and Google Cloud Storage. I have done everything specified here https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/hosting-static-website

Say I have the following file structure:

```
- index.html
- folder
    - index.html
    - another.html
```

I enter `www.example.com/folder`.

It redirects to `www.example.com/folder/index.html` => index.html is undesired

But if I enter `www.example.com/folder/`, it doesn't redirect and serves correctly the index.html page transparently.

How do I prevent the first behavior? Or automatically add a trailing slash?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution to this? The answer citing setting the MainPageSuffix doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: facing this issue as well. this is annoying. was thinking about using a small javascript snippet to "spank" the `.../index.html` to `.../`

Comment: You have to describe routing rules in app.yaml. How does your app.yaml look like?

Comment: @V.Tran they're describing Google Cloud Storage static website hosting - it's not related to app engine.

Comment: @JossefHarush This tutorial explain how to host a static website (Usually a single page web app built on Angular or React, these website routing won't work well if hosted using bucket. https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/getting-started/hosting-a-static-website#:~:text=You%20can%20use%20Google%20App,Engine%20provides%20a%20free%20tier.

Comment: @LouisSayers The purpose is to host a static site. You bind one solution into the problem, which is hosting a static site using GC Storage.

Comment: @V.Tran - yes that is a solution, but it is not the answer to this question. Specifically they want to know about routing rules within GCS. Basically what you're saying is "don't use GCS", but that's not helping in solving this issue, it's simply diverting someone away from this technology to a different one.

Comment: For anyone experiencing this issue, you might want to follow https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/151713401

Answer (score 2):

As per https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/hosting-static-website this behaviour is intended. As to whether it's desirable, that's a bigger issue.

> For example, say you set the MainPageSuffix of your static website to
>   index.html. Additionally, say you have no file named directory in your
>   bucket www.example.com. In this situation, if a user requests the URL
>   http://www.example.com/directory, Cloud Storage attempts to serve the
>   file www.example.com/directory/index.html. If that file also doesn't
>   exist, Cloud Storage returns an error page.
>
> The MainPageSuffix also controls the file served when users request
>   the top level site. Continuing the above example, if a user requests
>   http://www.example.com, Cloud Storage attempts to serve the file
>   www.example.com/index.html

Unfortunately I do not know of a way to automatically add the trailing slash. Perhaps you could add a message on index.html to the tune of "Did you mean to go to http://example.com/thisfolder/ instead of http://example.com/thisfolder/index.html", but this is something of a kludgy workaround.

Comment: I've read the documentation indeed, but it should serve `index.html` in the background, and not actually do a 301 redirect. It works for the root directory. `www.example.com` does not get `index.html` attached, but once you go to a subdirectory, the `index.html` is added (by redirect)

Answer (score 2):

[Firebase Hosting](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting) might be easier than using a bucket, because one can define [rewrite rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#rewrites) there.

Comment: Even though this doesn't really answer the question, it does provide a very interesting alternative. So it probably shouldn't be marked as answer, but you'll get the bounty :)

Comment: @PierreDuc with [gsutil](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/web) it might not be possible to set `index.html` as an actual "directory index" for a bucket, alike apache2 has it as directive. one bucket per such directory might be the only option ...it actually reads "main page" (`MainPageSuffix`) and not "directory index".

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up! There seem to be a lot of interesting redirection options though, strange that I've never noticed firebase hosting before :)

Answer (score 1):

If you only have a few pages and the site layout doesn't change often, you can use [traffic management for the global external application load balancer](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/setting-up-global-traffic-mgmt) to [rewrite the requested urls](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/setting-up-global-traffic-mgmt#rewrite_the_requested_url) to serve the index.html pages transparently at the 'directory' location (i.e. without the slash or index.html):

```
defaultService: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/{YOUR_PROJECT_ID}/global/backendBuckets/{YOUR_BUCKET_BACKEND_ID}
hostRules:
- hosts:
  - www.example.com
  pathMatcher: static
pathMatchers:
- defaultService: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/{YOUR_PROJECT_ID}/global/backendBuckets/{YOUR_BUCKET_BACKEND_ID}
  name: static
  routeRules:
  - matchRules:
    - prefixMatch: /folder
    priority: 10
    routeAction:
      urlRewrite:
        pathPrefixRewrite: /folder/index.html
    service: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/{YOUR_PROJECT_ID}/global/backendBuckets/{YOUR_BUCKET_BACKEND_ID}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to set the [MainPageSuffix](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/web) to the index.html accordingly. For more information, check the additional notes available in [public documentation link](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/web#description). Reference example can be found in the same documentation.

Syntax:

```
gsutil web set [-m main_page_suffix] bucket_url
```

Answer (score -2):

If you follow the tutorial above, then you must have a app.yaml file to describe your routing rules. Here is an answer for that:

[Angular 7 Routing in Google Cloud App Engine not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55863502/angular-7-routing-in-google-cloud-app-engine-not-working)

Answer (score -2):

Check this out

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/web#description

> The main_page_suffix applies to each subdirectory of the bucket. For example, with the main_page_suffix configured to be index.html, a GET request for http://www.example.com would retrieve http://www.example.com/index.html, and a GET request for http://www.example.com/photos would retrieve http://www.example.com/photos/index.html.