# How can I force trailing slash in static site hosted on Google Cloud Storage?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, web, google-cloud-storage, gsutil

I have a website hosted on a Google Cloud Storage bucket, following the instructions on https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/hosting-static-website. The site works, but navigating to any subdirectory page directly, such as https://example.com/blog, will redirect me to https://example.com/blog/index.html, and sometimes this results in another redirect to my 404 page. If I start at https://example.com, and navigate elsewhere, the site works fine.

This is with the MainPageSuffix set to index.html and NotFoundPage set to 404.html.

If I navigate to a subdirectory page with a trailing slash at the end (e.g. https://example.com/blog/), the site works fine. I’ve also looked st the troubleshooting advice for 301s, and it running through the steps did not work for me.

Is there any way to enforce the trailing slash for GCS buckets  as a static site? If not, how can I get around the issues I am seeing with redirects to index.html?

Comment: Same issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47910941/gcp-static-hosting-redirects-to-index-html

Answer (score 1):

If your MainPageSuffix is index.html, when you try to access a subdirectory directly such as https:// example.com/blog as you indicated, the service try to look for the target object or https:// example.com/blog/index.html. Same is also true for https:// example.com/blog/ assuming no zero-byte object exists for /blog/. In case a zero byte empty object exists for /blog/, [See the Troubleshooting topic](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/troubleshooting#empty-obj) for removing this zero byte object. When the zero byte object is removed the system will show https:// example.com/blog/index.html. If no such object exists the system will show an error page "404.html" if it is set for NotFoundPage.

In your case if you include an index.html file under the subdirectory /blog/ it should resolve the issue by displaying the https:// example.com/blog/index.html page in both scenarios https://example.com/blog or https://example.com/blog/. Alternatively you need to provide the full path to access any particular object within the subdirectory.

For further info on how subdirectory works see the following links.

[How Subdirectories Work](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/HowSubdirectoriesWork)

From [Recommended: Assigning specialty pages](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/hosting-static-website#specialty-pages):

An index page (also called a [webserver directory index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webserver_directory_index) is a file served to visitors when they request a URL that doesn't have an associated file. When you assign a MainPageSuffix, Cloud Storage looks for a file with that name whose prefix matches the URL the visitor requested.

For example, say you set the MainPageSuffix of your static website to index.html. Additionally, say you have no file named directory in your bucket www.example.com. In this situation, if a user requests the URL http://www.example.com/directory, Cloud Storage attempts to serve the file www.example.com/directory/index.html. If that file doesn't exist, Cloud Storage returns an error page.

The MainPageSuffix also controls the file served when users request the top level site. Continuing the above example, if a user requests http://www.example.com, Cloud Storage attempts to serve the file www.example.com/index.html.

If you are still experiencing any issues, please provide the breakdown of your website so that specific solution for your problem can be provided and also indicate what specific outcome you are expecting.

For info, I intentionally inserted a space after each http:// to avoid including so many links in this post.