# Nuxt SSG app not routing correctly on google cloud bucket, goes to dir/index.html on reload

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, nuxt.js

I followed this [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/hosting-static-website#console_2) on how to host server side generated sites on Google Cloud Buckets. The issue I am having is that the nuxt app works fine when routing internally, but when I reload a route, the site is redirected to whatever route plus a `/index.html` at the end.

This causes things to break, as it conflicts with Nuxt routing. I set index to be my entry point ala

```
gsutil web set -m index.html -e 404.html gs://my-static-assets
```

but it seems to assume that to be the case always. I don't have this problem using Netlify.

Answer (score 0):

According to the tutorial that you're doing, you're redirected to `/route/index.html` because of your [`MainPageSuffix`](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/hosting-static-website#specialty-pages) index, this means that when you try to access for example `https://example.com/route` the service look for the target https:// example.com/route/index.html.

To fix this I suggest that you include an `index.html` file under the subdirectory in the subdirectory of the route.

I recommend, for further info on this to check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52636195/9330208) which has a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have develop internal dashboard with same deploy strategy

As we know NuxtJS if we have route eg: domain.com/merchant/registration

will generate files & directories ;

```
-- index.html
-- merchant/index.html
-- merchant/registration/index.html
```

So I make middleware to redirect sub route

```
# middleware/trailingSlash.js

export default function ({ route, redirect }) {
  if (route.path !== '/' && route.path.endsWith('/')) {
    const { path, query, hash } = route
    const nextPath = path.replace(/\/+$/, '') || '/'
    const nextRoute = { path: nextPath, query, hash }
    redirect(nextRoute)
  }
  if (route.path !== '/' && route.path.endsWith('/index.html')) {
    const { path, query, hash } = route
    const nextPath = path.replace('/index.html', '') || '/'
    const nextRoute = { path: nextPath, query, hash }
    redirect(nextRoute)
  }
}
```

Dont forget to setup router on nuxt.config.js

```
...
  router: {
    trailingSlash: false,
    middleware: 'trailingSlash',
  },
...
```

Hope it helps reload issues

PS: but still it has index.html flashing in the address bar which is not good if the web app will be use for regular user