# Angular 7 Routing in Google Cloud App Engine not working

Tags: angular, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sdk

I've published an angular 7 Application to Google Cloud App Engine.

The index page is loading, but the subdirectorys give me

```
Error: Not Found
The requested URL /admin was not found on this server.
```

This is my app.yaml:

```
runtime: nodejs10


env_variables:
environment: "--prod"

handlers:

  - url: /
    static_files: dist/XXX/index.html
    upload: dist/XXX/index.html
  - url: /
    static_dir: dist/XXX/
  - url: /.*
    secure: always
    script: auto
```

Edit:
I finally figured out, how the routing in app.yaml works for Angular Applications.
Here is my working app.yaml:

```
runtime: nodejs10

env_variables:
  environment: "--prod"

handlers:

- url: /
  secure: always
  static_files: dist/index.html
  upload: dist/.*
- url: /(.*\.js)
  secure: always
  redirect_http_response_code: 301
  static_files: dist/\1
  upload: dist/.*\.js
- url: /(.*\.css)
  secure: always
  redirect_http_response_code: 301
  static_files: dist/\1
  mime_type: text/css
  upload: dist/.*\.css
- url: /.*
  secure: always
  static_files: dist/index.html
  upload: dist/.*
```

Comment: Only this worked for me.

Comment: Could've posted the solution as an answer, but it seems to work fine.

Answer (score 3):

I think your routing rules in handlers work fine if your resource files are only js and css. If you have image files, audio files, etc, you must use a more generic routing rule with regex:

```
handlers:
  - url: /
    secure: always
    static_files: www/index.html
    upload: www/index.html

  #  Routing rules for resources, css, js, images etc. Any file with format filename.ext
  - url: /(.*\.(.+))$
    secure: always
    static_files: www/\1
    upload: www/(.*\.(.+))$

  #  Routing rule for Angular Routing
  - url: /(.*)
    secure: always
    static_files: www/index.html
    upload: www/index.html
```

The idea is the same, but syntactically, a wild card match for any files with format filename.* will handle all the resource files.

Comment: this is a better approach than the self-answer in the question OP.