# GCP - How do you create a URL Redirect path rule with gcloud url-maps?

Tags: redirect, google-cloud-platform, load-balancing, gcloud, google-cloud-url-maps

I want to create a GCP Load Balancer path redirect rule programatically using the gcloud tool.

As a test, I created one manually through the GCP Console web interface.

For my manually created rule, `gcloud compute url-maps describe my-url-map` returns something that looks like:

```
creationTimestamp: '2021-02-23T20:26:04.825-08:00'
defaultService: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/my-project/global/backendServices/my-backend-service
fingerprint: abcdefg=
hostRules:
- hosts:
  - blah.my-site.com
  pathMatcher: path-matcher-1
id: '12345678'
kind: compute#urlMap
name: my-url-map
pathMatchers:
- defaultService: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/my-project/global/backendServices/my-backend-service
  name: path-matcher-1
  pathRules:
  - paths:
    - /my-redirect-to-root
    urlRedirect:
      httpsRedirect: false
      pathRedirect: /
      redirectResponseCode: MOVED_PERMANENTLY_DEFAULT
      stripQuery: false
selfLink: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/my-project/global/urlMaps/my-url-map
```

What I would like to do is to recreate the urlRedirect rule above (redirecting from `/my-redirect-to-root` to `/`), but using the `gcloud` tool.

Looking through [the gcloud docs](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/url-maps/add-path-matcher) I can't seem to find anything referring to redirects. Is it that this is not possible to do via the `gcloud` tool? and if not, is there any other solution for creating these redirect rules programatically?

I'm basically trying to get around [another GCP issue to do with GCS URLs for static websites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47910941/gcp-static-hosting-redirects-to-index-html?noredirect=1#comment120085828_47910941) by using Load Balancer redirects for each folder in our static site (~400 folders).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently Cloud SDK does not support creating url maps with redirects.
If you think that functionality should be available, you can create a Feature Request at [Public Issue Tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) to have this option added in future.

For now, you can use [API](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/urlMaps) which allows creating url maps with redirects.